# unable to upload Paginated report

Tags: migration, report

I want to migrate ssrs (.rdl files) from visual studio 2019 to Power bi service(2023). When i am trying to upload local copy of (.rdl files) in power bi report server throws below error
Unable to upload paginated report
Report is invalid. ErrorCode: rsInvalidReportDefinition, Details: The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services. The report definition may have been created with a later version of Reporting Services, or contain content that is not well-formed or not valid based on Reporting Services schemas. Details: String reference not set to an instance of a String. Parameter name: s.

I checked the bin version in Visual studio it is showing same 2016.
Please suggest me some solution.